# Show that a sequence is between a range

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I got this question in class which I'm having trouble proving
I tried investigate the sequence a little bit but it doesn't seem like I'm doing the right think, some help?

$ \frac{39}{e^2} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4n^2-1}{e^n} - \frac{3}{e} \le \frac{54}{e^2} $

Thanks!

Comment: Is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(4n^2-1)x^n$ a power series you recognize?